# Rgex get a part of string: Twig

Tags: twig

I have kind of string composed of numbers separated with `/`, for example:

- /11/12/485/
- /476/99/
- /956/

I want to filter the string to get always the first number:

- 11
- 476
- 956

Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure about twig but for regex `/([0-9]+)` should do it. Then use capture group 1.

Answer (score 0):

This expression `[\d]{1}` will give you one occurence to each number, so you grab first and that's it.

Comment: `[\d]{1}` is the same as `\d`. I don't think that is what the OP wants though. Also not sure if twig uses PCRE.